# How does browser zoom affect pixels defined in CSS?

Tags: html, css, zooming

For example: I have an element with width of 300px. Then if I zoom in I still have element with width of 300px but every css pixel will be bigger. But if I set max-width: 1000px and then will be zoom in at one moment element start shrink width. Why?

Comment: The question part of this is quite confusing, what is the question?

Comment: The question is why max-width will become smaller if user zoom in

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because the max-width is to prevent the element from scaling above 1000px, anytime the container width or screen with is less than 1000px the element will be responsive to 50% of the width.

```
element {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

When setting a fixed width of 300px the element is no longer responsive and cannot resize according to the zoom or resizing of the screen. Therefore when zooming in the element is retaining it's size, so in the below code the max-width is not relevant as the element will never exceed 300px.

```
element {
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.